# Why Clang allocate std::complex so fast?

Tags: c++, performance, clang, compiler-optimization, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have tested the memory allocation performance for `std::complex<double>` array using GCC, Clang, and Intel C++ compilers. I found that there is a dramatic performance difference between these compilers. Clang is several orders of magnitude faster than other compilers.

Can anyone figures out the reason? Thanks so much! The test code, test environment, and test result details are attached below.

### Attachments

Here is the performance test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


double GetWallTime(void) {
  struct timeval time;
  if (gettimeofday(&time, NULL)) { return 0; }
  return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_usec * .000001;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  auto size = atol(argv[1]);

  auto time_now = GetWallTime();
  auto double_array = new double [size];
  std::cout << "allocate double[" << size << "]: use "
            << GetWallTime() - time_now   << " sec" << std::endl;
  delete[] double_array;

  time_now = GetWallTime();
  auto c99cplx_array = new double _Complex [size];
  std::cout << "allocate double _Complex[" << size << "]: use "
            << GetWallTime() - time_now  << " sec" << std::endl;
  delete[] c99cplx_array;

  time_now = GetWallTime();
  auto stdcplx_array = new std::complex<double> [size];
  std::cout << "allocate std::complex<double>[" << size << "]: use "
            << GetWallTime() - time_now         << " sec" << std::endl;
  delete[] stdcplx_array;
  return 0;
}
```

On a Linux machine with Xeon E5-2680 v2 *2 CPUs and 64G DDR3 memory, I compiler this code using these three compilers and run the test. I obtain the following results:

Use `g++` 7.5.0 with `--std=c++11 -O3` flags:

```
allocate double[10000000]: use 5.6982e-05 sec
allocate double _Complex[10000000]: use 1.71661e-05 sec
allocate std::complex<double>[10000000]: use 0.0911679 sec
```

Use `icpc` 19.1.0.166 with `--std=c++11 -O3` flags:

```
allocate double[10000000]: use 7.41482e-05 sec
allocate double _Complex[10000000]: use 1.69277e-05 sec
allocate std::complex<double>[10000000]: use 0.087034 sec
```

Use `clang++` with the version

```
> clang++ --version
Intel(R) oneAPI DPC++ Compiler 2021.1-beta03 (2019.10.0.1121)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

with `--std=c++11 -O3` flags:

```
allocate double[10000000]: use 4.19617e-05 sec
allocate double _Complex[10000000]: use 9.53674e-07 sec
allocate std::complex<double>[10000000]: use 1.19209e-06 sec
```

Comment: Let's see: .0000171661 seconds versus  .000000953674 seconds, if I did my math right. These tiny, tiny time intervals, I think, are stretching the granularity of the system clock and, as such, are mostly meaningless.

Comment: `clang` is optimizing out all allocations. Wonder if he is allowed to do that. If we add `volatile` to the variables, the result get's pretty similar. The `std::complex<double>` takes longer because it is initialized.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks to the comment, please see the third row. 9.11679e-02 vs 1.19209e-06.

Comment: The code is too easy to analyze and optimize it all away.  Add some logic which can't be optimized away like setting a global variable with a result.  Furthermore, it should be repeated within a loop (like a million or a billion) to be in the range of the timer resolution and precision.

Comment: Rolled back the edit -- this site uses a Question and Answer format, you should not post Answers in the Question box .  Instead you can Accept a posted answer, and you can post your own answer if you want to make additional contributions which answer the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your test is a terrible one. Clang has simply removed the new/delete completely because it's pointless. You are effectively profiling this:

```cpp
#include <complex>
int main() {

    auto ptr = new std::complex<double>[1000];
    delete [] ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Which clang has correctly reduced to:

```
main:                                   # @main
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4JjXfh

gcc on the other hand allocates and frees the memory. You aren't testing allocation speed, you are testing a nothing burger. Don't micro benchmark like this, instead use a profiler on *actual code*.

If you want to profile this, do:

```cpp
volatile auto stdcplx_array = new std::complex<double> [size];
```

Which will provide an accurate benchmark for each compiler *(not that your benchmark is worth doing - it will just reduce to a new + memset + delete)*.

Comment: does `volatile` prevent reuse previously released memory? (iirc they don't, so it may still cause a difference)